# How do i set up a default for ActiveAuthenticationSchemes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ASP.Net Core 2 project, I have a custom `AuthenticationHandler` middleware that i want to plug in.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public BasicAuthenticationMiddleware(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("User"), null);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), "BasicAuth");
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

In my startup I have the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "BasicAuth";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "BasicAuth";
        options.AddScheme("BasicAuth", x => {
            x.DisplayName = "BasicAuthenticationMiddleware";
            x.HandlerType = typeof(BasicAuthenticationMiddleware);
        });
    });
}
```

And finally my view controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values/Works
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Works")]
    [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuth")]
    public string Works()
    {
        return "works";
    }

    // GET api/values/DoesNotWork
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("DoesNotWork")]
    [Authorize]
    public string DoesNotWork()
    {
        return "does not work";
    }

}
```

My authenticator `HandleAuthenticateAsync` will be called when I specify `ActiveAuthenticationSchemes` to my scheme name, but otherwise it will not.  I have a demo app showing the behavior here: https://github.com/JohnPAguirre/AuthenticationSchemaProblem

I want my `BasicAuthenticationMiddleware` to log everyone in with my demo logic. How can i make the `ActiveAuthenticationSchemes` default to "BasicAuth" for all requests?

Anyone have any ideas on what I could be missing?

Comment: `Authorize` with no parameters will just check that the user is logged in, nothing more really. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I want my BasicAuthenticationMiddleware to log everyone in with my demo logic. How can i make the ActiveAuthenticationSchemes default to "BasicAuth" for all requests?

Comment: i would recommend having "BasicAuth" declared as a constant preferably in your `BasicAuthenticationMiddleware` class. You don't want to have a typo while writing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can set a default, but you have some other options.

1. Create your own custom authorisation attribute:

   ```
   public class BasicAuthAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
   {
       public BasicAuthAuthorizeAttribute()
       {
           ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuth";
       }
   }
   ```

   And use it on your actions like you would before:

   ```
   [BasicAuthAuthorize]
   public string SomeAction()
   {
       //snip
   }
   ```
2. Add the `Authorize` attribute to all your actions and only override it where needed. To do that, in your `` method:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc(options =>
       {
           options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute
           {
               ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuth" 
           });

       });

       //snip
   }
   ```

   And overriding it:

   ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public string UnsecureAction()
   {
       //snip
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

I did manage to set a default authentication scheme By setting the scheme I want as the only authentication scheme of the DefaultPolicy for authorization. Use the following below in your config. I have used it in between `AddMvc` and `AddAuthentication` and it works fine.

```
services.AddAuthorization(config => {
    var def = config.DefaultPolicy;
    config.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(def.Requirements, 
        new List<string>(){ "BasicAuth" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar code and it works perfectly. Main difference I see is I used the `AddScheme` function chaining `AddAuthentication` instead of inside it's config.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "BasicAuth";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "BasicAuth";
})
AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationMiddleware>
    ("BasicAuth", "BasicAuthenticationMiddleware", x => { });
```

Rest of the code seems fine.